# Get all email addresses from GMAIL with whom I exchanged emails

Tags: email, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I want to get email addresses from my account with API. I can get those emails from my contacts, but don't succeed to get those emails who are not in my contacts, but I had email conversations with them before. From where I can get any doc or information how to get that information from API?

Answer (score 1):

I think your only option is going to be doing a [user.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) loop though each message and run a [user.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) and check the sender email address.

The API doesn't return the the information you are looking for.   You could also just start adding these people to your contacts.

Its an interesting idea you may want to submit it as a feature request.  [Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191602%2B)

Comment: Your idea definitely can work but user will not want to give access to get his/ger messages to my application.

Comment: There is no way to find out who a user has been in contact with but not added to there google Contacts.   Also try google people api